# How do we know which CNContainer represents iCloud?

Tags: ios, contacts

[Also asked on the Apple dev forums](https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/83860#83860).

Its [type](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Contacts/Reference/CNContainer_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CNContainer/type) is CNContainerType.CardDAV.

In my testing, its name is "Card". Is that universal?

Comment: Oh, that's fine. `containersMatchingPredicate(nil).first {$0.isiCloud}` will return nil, and I'll deal with it, but I'd like to favor iCloud.

Comment: I don't even think $0.isiCloud would work. CNContainer doesn't have that property?, how did you came up with it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Contacts framework does not provide information as to whether a particular container corresponds to iCloud. You are guaranteed that if the iCloud container is present, it will be of type `CardDAV`. Otherwise, you have no knowledge. If you need more, and you have a good use case, file a bug report with Apple.

Comment: It was somewhat implied through some fantastic wordsmithing in here, but there can also be other `CardDAV` containers/sources that won't be iCloud. There is no way to distinguish between a container/source that is actually iCloud and one that is named iCloud.